# VBA - Can't get Element by Tag Name

Tags: html, vba, excel

I've been playing around with some VBA for a while now, trying to check a specific instance of a tag name in an HTML document against an user inputted value. Basically, in the HTML doc I want to search out the 13th "label" tag and check if it matches the cell value in the excel doc. Here's the portion of the VBA...

```
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Dim promo As IHTMLElementCollection

Set promo = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("label")(12)

If InStr(promo.innerText, Range("E5").Value) = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i) = "Yes"
Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i) = "No"
End If
```

I keep getting an "Object variable or With block variable not set" error when I run the code. I've tried adjusting the promo object type and get the same error, tried to set the promo variable using different criteria (by classname, by ID, etc.) and I just cannot get past the errors. Here's a sample of the HTML, as you can see there are multiple "label" tags and I only need to compare against one in particular then move on...

```
    <div id="formHeader">Telephone:</div>
    <div id="formContent">Telephone Type: <br/>
    <label class="formResult">HOME</label> <br/>
    Telephone Consent: <br/>
    <label class="formResult">Y</label><br/>
    Country Code: <br/>
    <label class="formResult">1</label> <br/>
    Telephone: <br/>
    <label class="formResult">555 - 555-5555</label> <br/>
    Extension: <br/>
    <label class="formResult"></label> <br/>
    </div>
```

I'm not so great with VBA so I imagine this is probably a pretty simple fix but I'm just stumped... any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues I see include declaring `promo` incorrectly and not checking that `promo` is valid.  Can you guarantee you always have 13 labels?  I would guess `promo` is `Nothing` and then you refer to a property of that object.  Keeping this in mind, try the following code:

```
   Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
   Loop

   Dim promo As IHTMLElement

   Set promo = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("label")(12)

   If Not promo Is Nothing Then
      If InStr(promo.innerText, Range("E5").Value) = 0 Then
          ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i) = "Yes"
      Else
          ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i) = "No"
      End If
   End If
```

Answer (score 0):

While getElementsByTagName returns a collection, qualifying your reference with an item returns a single element.  Therefore, you should declare your variable as follows...

```
Dim promo As IHTMLElement
```

Hope this helps!